# Why does this line of Perl contain only a variable by itself?

Tags: perl, variables, subroutine

I like  perl the more I am getting into it but I had a question about a line I saw in a subroutine in a module I am looking through.

```
my $var = 1;
....
....
....
....
$var;
```

What throws me is just seeing that `$var` all by itself on a line. Is that just a roundabout way of returning `1` ?

Many thanks!

Jane

Comment: It was probably planned to return more cases or something, and was just never modified. Either that, or it could be a work around to appease some overzealous standards.

Comment: That can be an entire file.  Remember there’s the syntax `do $string_with_filename`, which returns the result of the last evaluated expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In perl the value of a block is the value of the last expression in the block.  That is just a shorthand for `return $var`.

EDIT:  Purists point out that that blocks *in general* do not return values (like they do in Scala, for example) so you can't write:

```
my $x = if (cond) { 7 } else { 8 };  # wrong!
```

The implicit return value of a subroutine, eval or do FILE is the *last expression evaluated*.  That last expression *can* be inside a block, though:

```
sub f {
    my $cond = shift;
    if ($cond) { 7 } else { 8 }  # successfully returns 7 or 8 from f()
}
```

There is the superficial appearance of the if/else blocks returning a value, even though, strictly speaking, they don't.

Comment: its good to point out that all blocks, even `if(...) {...} else {...}` blocks return their last executed expression.  In most cases it is not used, but can be if the structure is the last thing in a subroutine, or is encapsulated in a `do{...}` block

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. In Perl, blocks do not *per se* return anything. You’re just seeing a `sub/do/eval` produce the result of whatever it last evaluated, which is completely unrelated to **BLOCK** structure.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Ben. That’s right, or much *much* closer to right, now. Bare blocks and all the other forms of loops have no sort of return value; if they did, we’d not need `map/grep`. It’s good to just say `do` and `eval`, since while both have two forms, the same rule applies. Some subroutines do have two different return values, kinda: one for declaration `$fn = sub { ... };` and one for execution `$value = &$fn`. And I prefer to think of myself not so much a *purist* as a *precisionist*, even though that’s just obfuscatory Latin for *niggler*. ☺

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the last line of [`perldoc -f return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html):

> In the absence of an explicit `return`, a subroutine, eval, or do FILE automatically returns the value of the last expression evaluated.